# How do I rig a Kino Flo to a gobo arm like this?

Tags: lighting

I want to know how to rig a 4-bank Kino to a gobo arm like this. I can tell they're using two arms, but I don't understand how it is attached to the first, nor do I know what mounting plate they have on the Kino.

[film set with Kino on C-stand http://provideocoalition.com/images/uploads/fbm-makeoutpict.jpg](http://provideocoalition.com/images/uploads/fbm-makeoutpict.jpg)

Most photos I've seen just have the Kino with its own lollipop, right into a knuckle.

[Back of Kino Flo on C-Stand http://tanklightsyouup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/two-kinos.jpg](http://tanklightsyouup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/two-kinos.jpg)

Comment: I couldn't find anything official online, so it seems like it is clearly a custom job of some type.  It is also worth noting that there does appear to still be something positioned near the center attachment point as well.  The mount plate itself doesn't seem that complex, so they may have just machined something themselves.  A piece of sheet metal could probably be used with some bolts and such put through it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photo shows two grip heads, two arms and a c-stand. The kino would have its normal mounting plate (the one in the second photo).

The two grip arms are interlaced together; this makes them trombone-able (adjustable in length), stronger, and gives the gag a longer reach. One grip head attaches the arms to the c-stand, another attaches the kino to the arms.

I use this rig all the time; it works better if the stand is a junior stand and the grip arms are attached to the junior stand with a junior lolly-pop (much stronger).

Cardellini clamps can indeed clamp a stud to many things, but they aren't the best tool for this rig: you want a 5/8" female receiver for the Kino, not a 5/8" stud.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production.SE Don.  Great answer.  Super minor thing, we generally don't use signatures on the answers (so we can avoid clutter), but there is a [profile section](http://video.stackexchange.com/users/edit/6182) on your user page that is great for that kind of thing and having more info about you.

Answer (score 0):

Get two or three Cardellini clamps (e.g: [http://www.amazon.com/End-Jaw-2E-Cardellini-Clamp/dp/B0055V49F6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0055V49F6).) Mini Cardellinis might be the right weight for Kinos.

You'll be able to attach anything to anything else!